# Saving changes to a jTable when edited whilst .jar is running

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable, save

I'm currently making a project in which I will be saving data to a table whilst using the program, only when I add information to the table and re-launch the program. it resets to its original state.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your code? I imagine it's **not** being saved to the table, despite what you say.

Comment: you don't have to change the data inside the table. you have to change the source where the table gets its data from

Comment: there currently isn't any code, I have used the table model and added some code to a button that adds a new row. to where and in what format should I be saving the contents and is it as simple as adding code to a 'save' button to do it?

Comment: A .jar file should be considered read-only.  If you want to change some data, write that data to a file in the user’s home directory, or a subdirectory like Documents.  Add code to your application’s startup to check for that file and read it if it exists.